# Muscat transit visa

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, oman, muscat, pegasus-airlines

I am an Indian citizen with a permanent residence permit for The Netherlands.
I am traveling to Amsterdam from Mumbai (India).
I have a visa for neither Muscat nor Turkey.
I am traveling from Mumbai to Muscat via one airline (Indigo).
And then I am traveling from Muscat to Amsterdam via Istanbul with Pegasus Airlines.

I am traveling without any checked-in baggage as I don't have a transit visa at Muscat (to get around the problem of doing self check-in at Muscat).

Because I can not go via passport control at Muscat, I would like to do online check-in and get boarding passes beforehand.

Do I still need a transit visa for Oman (Muscat)?
Can the first airline from Mumbai to Muscat (Indigo) deny me boarding because I don't have a transit visa?

Is TWOV (Transit Without Visa) not applicable to me?

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need a visa for Muscat. [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true) says

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa)
>
> Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. The connecting flight must be booked on the same ticket. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

You can check on the [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/) website